# Teensy as keyboard: error: 'keyboard_leds' was not declared in this scope

Tags: arm, arduino-ide, teensy

I'm new to Teensy, and I'm trying to write a program that allows it to act as a keyboard. To make my program more useful, I'd like to make it not try to act on any input until its drivers install. I saw on GitHub that a way to do this (assuming the user doesn't hit it themselves) is to instruct the program to hit caps lock until the LED turns on. The function I wrote looks like this:

```
void waitForInstall(){
    boolean currCaps = keyboard_leds;
    while ((currCaps & 2) == (keyboard_leds & 2)){
        delay(200);
        Keyboard.set_key1(KEY_CAPS_LOCK);
        Keyboard.send_now();
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this, Arduino IDE informs me that `'keyboard_leds' was not declared in this scope`. I'm sure I made a very basic mistake, but would anyone mind humoring me and giving me a push in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a header you need to include?

Comment: Did you include the "usb_keyboard.h" header?

Answer (score 0):

keyboard_leds is a variable delcared in usb_private.h. This doesn't get included by default, and explicitly including it caused duplicate method errors. I wound up adding this

> #include "usb_private.h"

to hardware/teensy/avr/cores/usb_hid/usb_hid.h

And that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Add `#include "usb_private.h"` to hardware/teensy/avr/cores/**usb_serial_hid/usb_api.h**

Comment: Hi Eric, 
It is not, the name of the file changed

Comment: Indeed. I've improved visibility of this detail in your answer and removed my downvote.

Answer (score -1):

You have to select which USB profile you want in the Tools => USB Type

It has to include "Keyboard" to define the keyboard_leds as available.

You probably want the "Serial + Keyboard + Mouse + Joystick" USB Type.